# d3.js Array with categories and numbers

Tags: javascript, charts, d3.js

d3js experts

I have these array

```
var dados = [
["Brasil", 20], 
["Canada", 31],
["Japao", 29],
["USA", 26],
["Inglaterra", 21],
["Nova Zelandia", 25],
["Turquia", 34]
];
```

I like to binding the array **dados** to my chart. **Country Names** to **Texts** and **Values** to **Bars**.

Is possible to do it directly? How to do it?

```
chart.selectAll("rect")
     .data(function(d, i) { return d[i][1];})
     .enter().append("rect")
     .attr("y", function(d) {return d[0];})
     .attr("width", x)
     .attr("height", y.rangeBand()-6)
     .attr("transform", "translate(4,0)");

chart.selectAll("text")
     .data(function(d, i) {return d[i][0];})
     .enter().append("text")
     ...
```

Thank you so much

---

I got the values with code bellow - in bold

```
 var x = d3.scale.linear()
     .domain([0, **d3.max(dados)[1]** ])
     .range([0, 500]);


 chart.selectAll("rect")
  .data(**dados**)
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("y", function(d) {return d[0];})
  .attr("width", **function(d) { return x(d[1]);}** )
  .attr("height", y.rangeBand()-6)
   .attr("transform", "translate(4,0)");
```

Comment: See bar chart tutorial http://mbostock.github.com/d3/tutorial/bar-1.html . Instead of `ruturn d;` for your data you could `return d[0]` and `return d[1]` for labels.

Comment: If that worked for you, please add the answer and mark it as "answered".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correction inner ** **

```
 var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, **d3.max(dados)[1]** ])
    .range([0, 500]);


 chart.selectAll("rect")
    .data(**dados**)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("y", function(d) {return d[0];})
    .attr("width", **function(d) { return x(d[1]);}** )
    .attr("height", y.rangeBand()-6)
    .attr("transform", "translate(4,0)");
```